# Populate reduce data from one collection to another Meteor Js

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I've got a bit of a design issue.

Say ive got two collections:

```
Colletion A stores apples ( _id , appleName )

Collection B stores apple votes ( _id , apple_id , enum(0,1) )
```

I would like to then return collection A with a reduce of collection B based on the apple_id to return the value of 0's to 1's as a property on the main object. ( like a score )

Example data :

collection A array

```
[{_id : 1, appleName : 'grannySmith'},{_id : 2, appleName : 'greenApple'},{_id : 3, appleName : 'anotherApple'}]
```

collection B array

```
[{_id : 1, appleId : 1, vote : 0}, {_id : 2, appleId : 1, vote : 1}, {_id : 3, appleId : 1, vote : 1}]
```

From this Im looking for collection A to return with a reduce of B

collection A array with reduce

```
[{_id : 1, appleName : 'grannySmith', score : 2},{_id : 2, appleName : 'greenApple'},{_id : 3, appleName : 'anotherApple'}]
```

See as it now has a score of 2 from the reduce of collection B with linked IDs

Comment: You should include some sample data and your expected result based on those data

Comment: @Khang cheers, just added some in then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would use aggregation to achieve it:

```
db.apple.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: 'score',
      localField: '_id',
      foreignField: 'appleId',
      as: 'scores',
    },
  }, {
    $unwind: {
      path: '$scores',
      preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true,
    },
  }, {
    $group: {
      _id: '$_id',
      appleName: {
        $first: '$appleName',
      },
      score: {
        $sum: '$scores.vote',
      }
    },
  }
])
```

Note: I use [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) in the first stage of this aggregation, you need to use Mongo 3.2 or above in order for it to work.

Comment: This seems to be the better way to do it thank you, have done a rough test with the 'apple' scenario so will go with this as the full answer.